# Does nirukta of yaksa has any direct/indirect reference to mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata, reference-request, nirukta

Does nirukta of yaksa has any direct/indirect reference to mahabharat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reference to Akrura in the Nirukta. This Akrura, is probably the same person who is regarded as the maternal uncle of Lord Krishna.

[Nirukta 2.2](http://vedicreserve.miu.edu/nirukta/nirukta.pdf)

[image]

Translation of this is mentioned [here](https://archive.org/details/nighantuniruktao00yaskuoft/page/22/mode/2up)

> Danda  (punishment)  is  derived  from (the  root)  dad,  meaning  to  hold.  **People  say,  '  Akrura  holds  the  jewel.**

The jewel mentioned here could be a reference to **Syamantaka mani**.

The translator Lakshman Sarup also [adds this in the notes](https://archive.org/details/nighantuniruktao00yaskuoft/page/224/mode/2up) -

[image]

It is possible, that this reference to Akrura, is an indirect reference to Mahabharata, but this is not certain.